# General VB.net issue with Skype API

Tags: vb.net, skype4com

Hello community of StackOverflow, this is my first post but I've been reading this for some time. I wouldn't ask for your help if it wasn't truly important. I have a problem that you might be able to easily solve, here it is:

```
Public Class Form1
Public WithEvents oskype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype

'HOOK EVENTS
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
    If Key = Keys.F7 Then
        'CODE HERE TO ANSWER SKYPE CALL
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

There you see that I have some code to hook keys at low level (like to make shortcuts) and I would like to answer a call when F7 is Pressed, but I don't know how to call the API in that case.

As a reference I show here an example of how I can answer the call automatically If skype is ringing:

```
'SKYPE CALLING EVENT
Private Sub oSkype_CallStatus(pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call, Status As SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus) Handles oskype.CallStatus
    If SKYPE4COMLib.TCallStatus.clsRinging Then
        pCall.Answer()
    End If
End Sub
```

The thing is that I can not set  pCall.Answer() or oskype.Answer() in the other block (or any other block such as a Button), it does not work.

I also tried to set a variable when F7 is pressed but then that variable is not updated while I am inside oSkype_CallStatus Sub.

Any help or hint will be awesome, Thank you in advance. BTW the code is longer but I think that is enough for you to understand my question.

---

Exceptions and Errors:

[Image Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtZl0.jpg)

I also detected the error code, which is HResult = -2147467259 but it turned to be an unspecified code:

```
0x80004005
E_FAIL
Unspecified
```

Comment: How do you want to answer the skype? Constantly wait in a loop until any signal comes in? Why can't you publically declare pCall on the load, and then be able to reference it in the keydown event? I think that last one might be your solution.

Comment: @sparkysword Thank you, that is the kind of thing I was looking for but could you help me to do it? I am very beginner with Object Oriented languages so I am a bit lost with that. From what I guess you mean to insert in Form_1 load event something like a object or variable declaration?

Comment: I tried something like Dim pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call and then use pCall.Answer() but did not work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your comment " Dim pCall As SKYPE4COMLib.Call " is your problem. You need to create a variable with a global scope, i.e. can be accessed everywhere. Dim or private variables are inaccessible from other subs or whatever wants to use it.

Try declaring it outside of a sub, just like your oskype.

```
Public Class Form1
Public WithEvents oskype As New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype
Public pCall as New SKYPE4COMLib.Call

'HOOK EVENTS
Private Sub kbHook_KeyDown(ByVal Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) Handles kbHook.KeyDown
 If Key = Keys.F7 Then
    Try 
       pCall.Answer()
    Catch ex as Exception  'BreakPoint Here
    End Try

   End If
End Sub
```

Notice that try/catch I added? In Vb.net, you can add that to catch/ignore or whatever whenever a problem happens. This will be very useful if you do a breakpoint/F9 at the ex line (I added a comment on it). When you do that, it will tell you the stack trace/error exactly. That way you can debug. For example, A null exception if you try to set something to a value when a integer is null or whatever. It's very useful to us also on stackflow, since you can then show us the error code and we can debug it.

Comments like "it doesn't work" doesn't help us help you. Comments like "It says x type of exception. What's that?" That will be really helpful to you since 9/10 a google of that exception type will get you your answer.

Hope this helps :D.

Comment: Thank you for your dedication, I learned about catching exceptions and tried myself to fix it, but I can not figure how to. I will update my original post with every information about the error I have.